How do I start a python program x times at the same time from terminal and print the output?
I am on Mac, and I need to execute this python program 5 times at the same time while giving each of them a parameter like this.
python program.py instance-1
python program.py instance-2
python program.py instance-3
python program.py instance-4
python program.py instance-5

I am thinking I should do this asynchronously, so I do this from a .sh file.
#!/bin/zsh

for i in {1..5}
    python program.py instance-$i &
done 

I think the ampersand (&) makes it async but now it only works in the background? Meanwhile I want to see the output in my terminal. How do I achieve this? I already tried the following and it also doesn't work.
#!/bin/zsh
for i in {1..5}
    python program.py instance-$i | tee /dev/tty &

done
wait

Does anyone have any idea? I am not exactly familiar with bash command in general. Also, I think it's zsh but I am not sure if there is any difference.

The output will go to your terminal whether the command is run in the background or foreground. What specific problem did you experience when you ran for i in {1..5}; do python program.py instance-$i &; done?

Regarding I think it's zsh - your shebang #!/bin/zsh specifically calls zsh to execute the script. Regarding I am not sure if there is any difference - yes there are differences, bash and zsh are 2 completely different shells.

The whole program should run for a few hours, but when I run that command it only prints something like this [2] 8329
[3] 8330
[4] 8331
[5] 8332
[6] 8333 then stops. Nothing else in the terminal. But when I check the background processes using ps aux | grep python I saw they're all running.

So that [2] 8329, etc. tells you that you successfully started the programs and shows you their process IDs and ps aux | grep '[p]ython' tells you they are actively running. Do you have some reason to think that they won't produce output after a few hours as you said they should run?

Yeah I see it's zsh but is there any difference in my code? I mean both zsh and bash use .sh extension right?

It's not that it's not producing any output after a few hours. It's after running that command, I immediately get nothing else in terminal except those random numbers. If it's running properly, I should get a stream of prints on the terminal for a few hours, but it's not.

I don't know zsh, just bash and a few other shells, so idk what the zsh syntax is for what you're trying to do, sorry. Hopefully it's the same as bash for that loop but I really don't know. Nothing in Unix uses any extension. A .sh file could contain a grocery list or a picture of your grandma, it doesn't matter. The only way to tell what a file contains is to open the file and look inside it. The file command can give some initial clues though.

Do you know how it's supposed to work in bash? I can change the default terminal from zsh to bash in my Mac if necessary. I just use zsh because that's the default.

The code in my comment will do what I think you want in bash and maybe also in zsh. The default bash on MacOS is an extremely old one (Apple avoiding licensing issues) so install a newer version if you're going to switch to bash. Bash is a more commonly used shell and more people would be able to help you. The only real zsh expert I know, Stéphane Chazelas, participates in questions over on StackExchange FWIW.

how are you exeucting the zsh script ... from the command line? via a crontab entry? some other means?  where is your python program sending it's output to? is it sending to stdout? a specific tty? to a log file? after executing the zsh script are you by any chance closing the terminal (or closing an ssh connection)? setting aside the zsh script ... if you manually run one instance of the python program at the command line ... does it print output to your terminal?

I just run it using './start_processes.sh' and no it doesn't save it into a file, I just want to see the print on terminal. I'm not closing the terminal. Yes if I run one instance if the python program it still prints the program into the terminal.

Can you post a minimal version of program.py so that others can see waht's wrong ?

If your script shebang is bash, it will be used regardless of your login shell

Also, try to run python unbuffered

My guess is that 5 copies of the program should run for a few hours create a huge load on your system and the time till (first) output may be longer than you expect.

zsh and bash use .sh extension right : A shell does not use any extension. While most people consider it good practice to use no extension at all for your shell script, you can use any extension you like, including .c or .java, if this makes you happy.
